# Laravel Nova validate unique on multiple fields on Update

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have table **EventRegistration** contains **'id', 'user_id', 'event_id'.**
A User can register for multiple Event but can not register TWICE. 
An Event can be attended by multiple User

I need a uniqueness combination of **'user_id'** and **'event_id'**

```
 BelongsTo::make( __('User'),'user')
             ->searchable()
             ->rules('required')
             ->creationRules(Rule::unique('event_registration','user_id')
                               ->where(function($query) use ($event_id){
                                  return $query->where('event_id',$event_id);
                               }))
             ->updateRules(Rule::unique('event_registration','user_id')
                               ->where(function($query) use ($event_id){
                                  return $query
                                        ->where('event_id',$event_id);

                               })
                               ->ignore($this->id),
                               // ->ignore('{{resourceId}}') // Does not work as well
    ),
```

Creation rule works well. Update rules show Error (the resource id is 5389)

> Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate5389 does not exist.

I guess Laravel is trying convert the ID for validation but fail to call the method. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried as well with `->ignore($this)`? But I suspect that the underlying code would be the same for both syntax.

Comment: Side note: that won't solve your problem, but you should be able to use `->where('event_id', $event_id)` directly on the unique rule instance instead of wrapping that call into a closure

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BelongsTo::make(__('User'), 'user')
    ->searchable()
    ->creationRules([
        'required',
        Rule::unique('event_registration', 'user_id')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($event_id) {
                return $query->where('event_id', $event_id);
            })
    ])
    ->updateRules([
        'required',
        Rule::unique('event_registration', 'user_id')
            ->where(function ($query) use ($event_id) {
                return $query->where('event_id', $event_id);
            })
            ->ignore($request->resourceId)
    ]),
```